# Displaying the same picture with math.random?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm working with Corona SDK and I want to display random color. This is my code, but my color is always the same. Why is that?

```
local boxColors = {
        "BoxColors/Gold.png",
        "BoxColors/Blue.png",
        "BoxColors/Green.png",
        "BoxColors/Orange.png",
        "BoxColors/Purple.png",
        "BoxColors/Rose.png",
        "BoxColors/Yellow.png"
    }

groundColor =display.newImage(boxColors[math.random(#boxColors)],0,0)
```

Thanks and kind reagrds

Comment: does it work if you use display.newImage(boxColors[1],0,0)? If not then its probably not the math.random thats broken

Comment: https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/301-display-a-random-image-every-shake/ -- Extremely similar to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how is your code, but I tried here and worked for me, I just need to add `groundColor:removeSelf()` before instantiating a new image, 'cause in Corona it's not overrided.

If you just change the color, try something like this:

```
local centerX = display.contentCenterX
local centerY = display.contentCenterY

local colors = {
    { 1,1,0 }, -- yellow
    { 0,0,1 }, -- blue
    { 0,1,0 }, -- green
    { 1,0,0 }, -- red
}

rect = display.newRect(centerX, centerY, 100, 100)
rect.fill = colors[math.random(#colors)]

function onTouch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        rect.fill = colors[math.random(#colors)]
    end
end
rect:addEventListener( "touch", onTouch )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neat little shuffle function I made ages ago. The randomness of math.random can be a bit iffy so the below function makes it a little more adventurous.

```
func shuffleArray(myArray) 

  for i=0,30 do -- Do the below 30 times
    for temp = 1, #myArray do 
        n = math.random(1, #myArray) -- Select a random index from myArray and assign it to n.
        temp1 = myArray[temp] -- Take the loop number(temp) as an index from myArray and assign it to temp1.
        myArray[temp] = myArray[n] -- Replace the temp index taken from above with the randomly selected SoundList index.
        myArray[n] = temp1 -- Replace the randomly chosen index with the temp index.
    end
  end

return myArray -- Return the shuffled array.
end
```

You simply call the function and pass an array into it or you can edit it how ever you want!

Kind Regards,

Krivvenz.